# How to call a google chrome screenshot extension from a javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a google chrome extension which generates screenshot of a active tab of a webpage and downloads it. It works fine on chrome when enabled. I want the same screenshot to be generated and downloaded on a button click in my webpage. How do I call that extension from a webpage?
My code for extension goes here:

### manifest.JSON

```
    {
      "name": "Screenshot Extension",
      "version": "1.0",
      "description": "A simple screenshot extension",
      "background": {
          "persistent": false,
          "scripts": ["background.js"]
     },
     "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "camera.png",
    "default_title": "Screenshot"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "activeTab"],
    "manifest_version": 2
    }
```

### background.js

```
    var screenshot = {
    content : document.createElement("canvas"),
    data : '',

    init : function() {
    this.initEvents();
    },

    saveScreenshot : function() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        var canvas = screenshot.content;
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        // save the image
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = "download.png";
        link.href = screenshot.content.toDataURL();
        link.click();
        screenshot.data = '';
    };
    image.src = screenshot.data; 
    },

    initEvents : function() {
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {
            format : "png",
            quality : 100
        }, function(data) {
            screenshot.data = data;

            // send an alert message to webpage
            chrome.tabs.query({
                active : true,
                currentWindow : true
            }, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {ready : "ready"}, 
            function(response) {

                        screenshot.saveScreenshot();

                                        });
            }); 

            });
            });
            }
         };

        screenshot.init();
```

### content.js

```
   chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, 
   sendResponse) {

   if (msg.ready === "ready") {
    if (confirm('Do you want to capture the screen?')) {
        sendResponse({download : "download"});
    }
   }

   });
```

Please help.

Comment: [Can a site invoke a browser extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10527809) or simply dispatch a CustomEvent from your web page and listen to it in the content script.

Comment: I have already tried it. But id doesn't work for me. Can you please post the code of how to get it done.

Comment: That's a lot to type... Can you show the code that didn't work so I simply fix it? :-)

Comment: @krishnabharadia, If you have already tried it, then you need [edit] the question to state that you have done so and include the code that did not work in the question. Right now, this question appears to be a duplicate of the one which wOxxOm linked, as you are asking the same thing and it is solved in the same way.

Comment: Please be explicit: Are you wanting to be able to activate the screenshot extension from *any* website, or only *your* website. Are you intending that the *website* calls your extension, or that you extension is listening for the user to click on a button in the website? Is this button one which is already in the website, or is it one which the extension has added?

Comment: Sry, My mistake.i tried the code in link posted by wOxxOm once again.. It worked for me now.Solved some logical errors which i committed last time when i tried it.Thanks for the help wOxxOm and Makyen..